# How to print Hello World in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to print Hello World in AngularJS, I have created javascript file named `testController`but unfortunately it shows this error

[image]

here is HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>AngularJS</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../app/controllers/testController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="testController">
        <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this `testController` code

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("testController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello, AngularJS";
});
```

Where is the issue ? can anyone explain ?

Comment: There is not enough information here to find the problem, I suggest you try changing a few things n post your learnings.. and also like @sachila mentions below, check your path to testController.js

Comment: As per the error message, `testController` is not found. Make sure that the path is correct, and also that you are using correct  */* or *\*.

Comment: I am trying to change a few things based one some suggestion provided here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error clearly stated that `testController` function haven't got register in `app` module. There is possibility that there could be more files involved in your application(you have shrink the code to have relevant information in post). It seems in each file you're redefining module every time before registering angular components like below

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myOtherController", function ($scope) {
    //Code here
});
```

So in this case what had happened is, `app` got created once again, and old registered component got wiped out. `myOtherController` got registered with `app` module. To fix the issue you should not be declaring module again & again. Define it once and use it in other places.

**app.module.js**

```
angular.module('app', []);
```

**testController.js**

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("myOtherController", function ($scope) {
    //Code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining clearly. The issue as you said  old registered component wiped out after creating `app` again.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything wrong with you code. So I tried it on works fine for me.

`Plunker    https://plnkr.co/edit/xSKHe6?p=preview`

Check Module Error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=app